# Add Info To ListView Line By Line

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, ping

I have a little problem in my code

i have code that Test IP  Ping

```
public class StartPinging extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

            try {

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -w 6 -c 6 " + String.valueOf(IP.getText()));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

               while ( (temp = reader.readLine()) != null){
                   Log.e("",temp);
                   pingAdapter.add(temp);
                   pingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

           reader.close();
           process.destroy();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    });
   return null;    }}
```

This code Work Fine
But i want the code to add the info line by line
just like the way it show in "LOG"

but in my code , the app freeze, until pinging is done,, then it show all lines at once in ListView

is there way to fix this?

and thanks

Comment: It's freeze 'cause you run in GUI thread...

Comment: um okey? what i should do now?

Comment: Implement ping logic in another thread, and send result of pings to handler in GUI thread.

Comment: You are using Assyn Task, so you can send ping result to GUI on onProgressUpdate method.

Comment: @Suvitruf i tried that, it didnt work

Comment: What do you mean "didnt work"? Did you have errors? Or, did it freeze GUI?

Comment: yes its freeze GUI , same result

Comment: protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  Log.e("","a");


-- it dont work. the LOG is not showing

Comment: @Squonk sry i'm still new in Android Developing, i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run inside the UI thread only the part realative to the ui change.

```
    public class StartPinging extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


             @Override
             public void run() {

                try {

                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -w 6 -c 6 " + String.valueOf(IP.getText()));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                while ( (temp = reader.readLine()) != null){
                   Log.e("",temp);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       pingAdapter.add(temp);
                       pingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                     
                   });
                 }

               reader.close();
               process.destroy();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

       return null;    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use runonuithread in doinbackground method.

In Asynctask, preExecute() and postExecute() are executes on thread so you can use that instead of runOnUiThread(),
and doInBackGround() executes on worker thread.